# How to change color of the icon in android R.drawable?

Tags: java, android

Hello I have the method which returns the int `R.drawable.icon_name`.
How can I set the color of that icon ?
Is there any possibility to return the 'int' with changing the color ?

I've tried the `R.color` but can I connect this two possibilities ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this please?

```
Drawable originalDrawable = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.icon_name); 
Drawable modifiedDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(originalDrawable);
DrawableCompat.setTint(modifiedDrawable, Color.RED);
```

P.S: I am using `DrawableCompat` here since it provides backwards compatibility and bug fixes on API 22 devices and earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the drawable using context.getDrawable(R.drawable.your_drawable)

and can simply set the tint color of your drawable using

```
var drawable = context.getDrawable(R.drawable.your_drawable)
drawable.setTint(R.color.your_color)
```

Another way would to give tint color directly to your imageView

1. in xml
2. or programatically.    `imageView.imageTintList=context.getColorStateList(R.color.your_color)`